# How do I hide a follower's helmet?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just installed the [Mjoll facelift](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=8415&searchtext=) mod and love it. The problem is that I have to remove all helmets from her inventory in other to see her face. Is there a way to hide whichever helmet my follower's wearing?

Comment: Can you link to the facelift mod? She's currently wearing the dwarven helmet for that's the closest to a paper bag.

Comment: @Renan Sure. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=8415&searchtext=

Comment: I've reworded the question to not ask specifically for a mod recommendation, and to ask for any solution instead. Voting to reopen as per the meta posts: […looking for mods for specific purposes](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11578/4797) "*Give us the actual problem… and we'll solve that, and if the solution involves a mod, so be it*", and [Closed 'mod recommendation' Skyrim question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5547/4797) "*This is not a shopping recommendation (a request for subjective… advice). The problem can be clearly stated and objectively evaluated in most cases.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There is indeed.](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/562) You can also select which helmets are hidden so certain followers or NPCs, like guards, can still display theirs.